# C++ pointer or header issues

Tags: c++, pointers, header-files

I have an example program whose main cpp file has

```
    Rectangle rect(5, 5);
    Triangle tri(5, 5);
    Shape *rectangle1 = &rect;
    Shape *triangle1 = &tri;
    rectangle1->setValues(3, 3);
    triangle1->setValues(3, 3);
    int area = rectangle1->getArea();

    std::cout << area << std::endl;
    area = triangle1->getArea();
    std::cout << area << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

The header files of rectangle, triangle and shape are as follows:

Rectangle.h

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

#include "Shape.h"

class Rectangle: public Shape {
public :
    int length;
    int width;
    Rectangle(int length, int width);
    int getArea();
    //Rectangle::~Rectangle(void);
};
#endif
```

Triangle.h

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_H
#define TRIANGLE_H

#include "Shape.h"

class Triangle: public Shape {
    public :
        int length;
        int width;
        Triangle(int length, int width);
        int getArea();
        //Triangle::~Triangle(void);
};

#endif
```

Shape.h

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H
#include <iostream>

class Shape 
{
    protected:
        int width;
        int length;
    public:
        Shape(int length, int width);
        void setValues(int length, int width);
        virtual int getArea() = 0;
};

#endif
#endif
```

The cpp files of shape, rectangle and triangle are as follows:

Rectangle.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
Rectangle::Rectangle(int length, int width): length(length), width(width), Shape(length, width)
{
}
    int Rectangle::getArea() {
        return length * width;
    }
```

Triangle.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Triangle.h"
Triangle::Triangle(int length, int width): length(length), width(width), Shape(length, width)
{
}
    int Triangle::getArea() 
    {
        return length/2 * width;
    }
```

Shape.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Shape.h"
#include <iostream>

Shape::Shape(int length, int width): length(length), width(width) {

}

void Shape::setValues(int length, int width) {
    this->length = length;
    this->width = width;
}
```

My line of thinking is that because triangle and rectangle inherit from Shape and I set rectangle1 to point to the rectangle object and triangle1 to point to the triangle object, once the 2 shapes are created with their default constructor values, I call setValue() (which should be available to all objects that inherit from Shape. This should change each shape's length and width values to 3, 3, and when I run getArea for each shape instance, rectangle should return 3*3 and triangle should return 3*1.5. However, they both return the original areas from before I called setValues (25 and 10).

Is there something I'm not understanding about my pointers or header files?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you are aware of integer division?

Comment: btw, you very likely need a virtual destructor in `Shape`.

Comment: Reading up on virtual destructors, I would need one if I created the shapes using "new", since it would be on the heap instead of the stack, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have separate `width` and `length` member variables in the *child* classes. So the `getArea` functions in the child classes will use those variables instead of the variables from the base class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in Shape you have widht and height but also in Rectangle class and Triangle class. This mean that in every instance of Triangle , you have 2 variables Width and height ( Shape::width and Triangle::width) since your function setValues is in shape, it will modify the variables in the shape class and the getArea is define in the rectangle class so it will use the variables in Rectangle)

The solution would be to remove these duplicates variables in Rectangle and Triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Triangle` and `Rectangle` shapes define their own `length` and `width` values, which hide the `Shape`'s `length` and `width`. But `Shape` is not aware of that - when you're using `setValues` it sets the base class's variables. But your `getArea` will use the child class values.